# how to play audio through earpiece only in windows phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-voip

I have tried with AudioRoutingManager class...but i got unauthorizedaccess exception.
here is my code

```
 AudioRoutingManager audioRouting = AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault();
    public AudioRoutingEndpoint ChangeAudioRoute()
    {

       var currentEndPoint= audioRouting.GetAudioEndpoint();
       switch (currentEndPoint)
       {
           case AudioRoutingEndpoint.Earpiece:
           case AudioRoutingEndpoint.Default:
               return AudioRoutingEndpoint.Speakerphone;

           case AudioRoutingEndpoint.Speakerphone:
               return AudioRoutingEndpoint.Earpiece;

               default:
               throw new OperationCanceledException();
       }
    }

    public void SetAudioRoute()
    {
        audioRouting.SetAudioEndpoint(this.ChangeAudioRoute());
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The APIs in the Windows.Phone.Media.Devices namespace require the ID_CAP_AUDIOROUTING and the ID_CAP_VOIP capability. (Add this to your manifest)

Also, it's only possible to change the audio routing while in a active VOIP call.

Additionally, you need to do the audio routing in your background VOIP process, and not in the foreground process.

Comment: Unfortunately we had tried this, added it to WMAppManifest.xml:
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_AUDIOROUTING" />. However, the following error is thrown:
Error 14 The 'Name' attribute is invalid - The value 'ID_CAP_AUDIOROUTING' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

Comment: Well that was a bit confusing. The capability for this specific manager is actually ID_CAP_VOIP. Using your code, you won't get an exception on the AudioRoutingManager. But I think you still will on SetAudioEndPoint unless a call is in progress.

Comment: I'm of the same view. From all MS examples, setting the endpoint is only available while a VOIP call is in progress. This would be consistent with the OS, where a call can only be changed to speaker after it is initiated.

Comment: Hey, just to confirm, you can only change the audio routing while in a (VOIP) call. *(I work for Microsoft/Skype on Windows Phone)*. I've updated your answer.

Comment: Updated with another note. The routing needs to be done in the background process.

Comment: Claus Jorgensen,is push service mandatory for incoming call? is there any other alternative that we can use to receive incoming call ?

like i want to use pjsip library,and want to run the pjsip library in the backgroung agent and receive incoming call from that library always without push notification,is it possible?

Comment: What's the equivalent to these capabilities in an 8.1 Universal App?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but now I know the answer.

Two things which you need to do:

1. Tag the audio in question as "communications"

How to do this depends on what API you're using. It could be as simple as . Or you might have to call IAudioClient2::SetClientProperties with an AudioClientProperties structure whose AudioClientProperties.eCategory = AudioCategory_Communications.

2. Tag your app as either a "voice over IP" app or a "voicemail" app
   You should add file called WindowsPhoneReservedAppInfo.xml  to your project with the following contents:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WindowsPhoneReservedAppInfo         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/phone/2013/windowsphonereservedappinfo">
      <SoftwareCapabilities>
        <SoftwareCapability Id="ID_CAP_VOIP" />
      </SoftwareCapabilities>
    </WindowsPhoneReservedAppInfo>
   ```

Look for more detailed explanation here:

[Playing audio to the earpiece from a Windows Phone 8.1 universal app](https://web.archive.org/web/20150416092356/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2015/03/05/playing-audio-to-the-earpiece-from-a-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app.aspx)