# AudioRoutingManager permissions on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, voip

hope everything is fine with you!

I got stuck trying to route my voip calls through earpiece on my windows phone 8.1 application. Before asking here, I did some google research and I found another thread called "[how to play audio through earpiece only in windows phone 8 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685019/how-to-play-audio-through-earpiece-only-in-windows-phone-8-application)".

There they suggest to use the AudioRoutingManager interface and it is available inside windows phone 8.1 SDK but whenever I call any method, the UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown. I can't add the ID_CAP_AUDIOROUTING and the ID_CAP_VOIP capabilities because they don't exist on windows phone 8.1 projects (I am using visual studio 2013).

Now one very important information: I am not using [microsoft.phone.networking.voip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.networking.voip%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) classes. I have my own SIP stack implemented in cpp which I have already ported for many platforms, like Android, IOS, MAC, Symbian, Linux and now windows phone. This sip stack is working very well on windows phone, I can make calls for PSTN numbers and the audio is connected on both parts but I can't route the audio through earpiece, it is only played through speakers and I always get this UnauthorizedAccessException exception when I try to change the audio routing mode.

I have run out of ideas here and I am really considering to drop the window phone project if I can't overcome this limitation. Any help wiil be appreciated.

Thanks